# How to get data from db per hour using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I set a cron which runs per 5 miniuts and values are added in db. Now i am looking for a code which will fetch a data from db per hour but it will take a latest entry of perticular hour so that i will get 24 different entries and each value is the latest entry for that hour

Thanks..

Comment: @Dasun: it just a simple db table stores time per entry. i tried to make it group by hour but not got a desired output.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field in your table, you can use the sql `BETWEEN()` function to look for a value within a certain range of time, then `ORDER BY timefield DESC LIMIT 1` to retrieve the last entry.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY datetime_field_name DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

For the PHP code refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp). You can find many more example if you search on google.